# ERROR 'Could not find javaw.exe in PATH'

Tags: windows-7, java

How can I troubleshoot this error?

The error: [image]

```
Could not find javaw.exe in PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add the path in which javaw.exe is located to the PATH environment variable.

To do so go to This PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Enviroment Variables.
Find the variable "Path" in the list with system variables and choose edit.
Click on new and add the path where javavw.exe is located.
The default path for the 32 bit version is something like this depending on the version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin
```

Using the symbolic link javapath is better because it won't break the path variable after each Java update. The path to the symbolic link:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`

It could be different for you if you use 64 bit Java but it is most likely that you run a 32 bit version of Java because this is the default even on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Posting an answer with a link is not good practice here on SuperUser. If the link becomes invalid, so will your answer. For that reason, I will not vote up your answer at this moment. If you however edit your answer and add the instructions to do so manually (it can be a copy/paste), I will happily give you a vote up. :)

Comment: Okay, I manually added some instructions and removed the link from the answer.

Comment: @shifty and got your 1st upvote. Nice answer!

Comment: +1 from me too. :) Good job. :)